# Python running bash script includes single quote in escaped character

Tags: python

I'm passing a parameter into a shell script and executing the script from python. The shell command has escaped characters `\( \)` but when I run from python its printed as string with single quotes:

```
import os
os.system('./myscript.sh 12ed34 > output.json')
```

and

```
--myscript.sh--
param=$1
api=someURL/api/data/v1.0/location

echo \(${param}\)

curl -X GET ${api}\(${param}\)
```

which should run

`curl -X GET someURL/api/data/v1.0/location\(12ed34\)`

but instead single quotes have been inserted:

`'curl -X GET someURL/api/data/v1.0/location\(12ed34\)'`

How to fix this such that it doesnt include the single quotes?

When I included `echo \(${param}\)` in the script, I get `'\(12ed34\)'`

Comment: What do you mean "single quotes have been inserted"? Python isn't rewriting your bash script. Who's inserting anything?

Comment: There's no way that Python can cause that.

Comment: The script needs a `#!` line at the top.

Comment: "its printed as" -- printed by *what*? Are you using `set -x` for logging, despite not showing its use in the code given here? What's doing the printing?

Comment: Either add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in `myscript.sh` or change the python call to `os.system('bash ./myscript.sh ...')`

Comment: That said, this is innately bug-prone code -- you should be using `subprocess.call(['./myscript.sh', '12ed34'], stdout=open('output.json', 'w'))` instead. And as @scnerd says, you should have a proper shebang (`#!/bin/bash`, or `#!/bin/sh` if writing the script for POSIX sh compatibility).

Comment: `echo \(${param}\)` in the script, is giving `'\(12ed34\)'`

Comment: I'd like to add that there's no reason to invoke some shell if all it does in turn is invoking cURL.

Comment: That's not all it does, I drilled down to the important parts